# add an element at the end of a linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Task is to append an element at the end of a linkedList using boolean

```
/**
* Appends the specified element to the end of this list
* @param element element to add to the list
* @return true
* @throws NullPointerException when element is null
*/
```

My solution

```
public boolean add(T element) {
    ListNode newElement = new ListNode (element);
    while (cur.link == !null) {
        cur = cur.link;
        cur.link = newElement(element, null); 
        if (cur==null) {
            throw new NullPointerException;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Need help in correcting my code.

Comment: It's not clear what your exact problem is.

Comment: Start by indenting your code properly. Then read the error messages you get from the compiler. Then execute your code step by step, on paper. What's the point of always returning true from a method? Why would adding an element at the end of a list throw an exception?

Comment: Why on earth are so many programmers so lazy in indenting when posting code? Additionally, this doesn't compile, and you should have told us!

Comment: I have fixed your indentation for you this time. Remember, people here are volunteering their time to try and help you, the least you can do is take the time to hit the space bar the correct amount of times.

Comment: whats your cur here? where its been declared/initialized

Comment: "Why would adding an element at the end of a list throw an exception?"
this is the task i got, i dont know why

Comment: because cur  is never inialized. so exception. (Assuming you have declared it somewhere)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make sure the `cur` variable is initialized to something and change the following line to use `!=` instead of `== !`

```
while (cur.link != null) {
```

This will help with compiling @rpax did the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the end of the list.

```
public boolean add(T element)
{

    ListNode cur= this.firstNode; //or something similar
    ListNode newElement = new ListNode (element);
    while (cur.link !=null) {
      cur=cur.link;
      // cur.link = newElement(element, null); 
    }
    //cur.link is null now
    cur.link = newElement(element, null); 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't compile!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose sorry, I forgot to change the `!=`